# List all IAM actions in a given AWS service

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

Is there a way in AWS SDK TypeScript to list all IAM actions in a given AWS Service?

*For example:*

**Service Name:** Lambda

**List of Actions:**

```
results = [
         "lambda:AddLayerVersionPermission",
         "lambda:AddPermission",
         "lambda:CreateAlias",
         "lambda:CreateCodeSigningConfig",
         "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
         "lambda:CreateFunction",
         "lambda:DeleteAlias",
         "lambda:DeleteCodeSigningConfig",
         "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
         "lambda:DeleteFunction",
         "lambda:DeleteFunctionCodeSigningConfig",
         "lambda:DeleteLayerVersion",
         "lambda:DeleteProvisionedConcurrencyConfig",
         ... etc
      ]
```

Comment: There is a library that may help you - https://www.npmjs.com/package/iam-floyd. Take a look if it has a method that lists actions. What's the use case?

Comment: Programmatically, you could examine the service models, which are buried somewhere in the SDK.  Alternately, you could just run `aws lambda help`.  Note that this will give an imperfect list: there are cases where the name of the permission does not match the name of the API action (`s3:ListBuckets` vs `s3:ListAllMyBuckets`), cases of permissions that do not have corresponding API actions (`iam:PassRole`), and cases of API actions that do not have corresponding permissions (`sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`).